# Select from within a fileliste of xml

Tags: xml, xslt, filelist

I use xslt 2.0 to transform xml data to xml files.
I created xsl to find all filenames in a folder, which worked fine:

**filenames.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<filelist>
   <file>birds2014.xml</file>
   <file>birds2013.xml</file>
</filelist>
```

Then I created a xsl to search within the xml-files to select all the names of the birds which are located in the tag `<spbird>` in all documents.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/> 
        <xsl:variable name="files" select="document('filelist.xml')/filelist/file"/>
            <xsl:element name="birdname">
                <xsl:for-each select="document($files)">    
                    <xsl:value-of select="//spbird">
                    </xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:template>
```

Result:

```
<birdname>Papagei Wellensittich Pfau</birdname>
<birdname>Papagei Wellensittich Pfau</birdname>
<birdname>Papagei Wellensittich Pfau</birdname>
<birdname>Papagei Wellensittich Pfau</birdname>
<birdname>Papagei Wellensittich Pfau</birdname>
<birdname>Papagei Wellensittich Pfau</birdname>
<birdname>Papagei Wellensittich Pfau</birdname>
<birdname>Papagei Wellensittich Pfau</birdname>
<birdname>Papagei Wellensittich Pfau</birdname>
```

Expected:

```
<birdname>Papagei</birdname>
<birdname>Wellensittich</birdname>
<birdname>Pfau</birdname>
```

Can anyone help?

**Edit**
I changed the

```
 <xsl:template match="*">
```

to

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
```

which resolves the issue of the same result showing up 9 times (where did this number came from).

Now with your help the result is:

```
<birdname>Papagei Wellensittich</birdname>
<birdname>Pfau</birdname>
```

`Pfau` is the bird in the second xml file. 
Only problem is, that document() seems to do a for-each on it's own. So I do not get all the birds listed seperately in a birdname tag..

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/> 
        <xsl:variable name="files" select="document('filelist.xml')/filelist/file"/>

                <xsl:for-each select="document($files)">   
                       <birdname> 
                         <xsl:value-of select="//spbird">
                       </birdname>
                    </xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your element inside of the `xsl:for-each`...

```
<xsl:for-each select="document($files)">    
    <birdname>
        <xsl:value-of select="//spbird"/>            
    </birdname>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note: Unless you're trying to dynamically build the element name, there's no reason to use `xsl:element`.

**Edit**

In XSLT 2.0, `xsl:value-of` will give you every value of `spbird`. Instead of a `xsl:for-each` on the document, you should do the for-each on the `spbird`. Try changing your `xsl:for-each` to the example below. If that doesn't work, please add an example of the bird files to your question.

```
<xsl:for-each select="document($files)//spbird">    
    <birdname>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>            
    </birdname>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: thx, changed it, see my edit...still not the result I expected.

Comment: @user3500768 - See my update. If that doesn't work, please update your question with examples of the bird xml (that contain `spbird`).

Comment: Yeah, this is logical, thanks a lot. Worked like charme.